AppCompatActivity fails to restore Compose Navigation back stack
I would like to know:
Have I encountered a Jetpack Compose bug
or am I doing something wrong?
The App below crashes with the exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Restoring the Navigation back stack failed: destination 132070424 cannot be found from the current destination ComposeNavGraph(0x0) startDestination={Destination(0xe362b7e) route=com.example.typesafenavigation.Login}

Way to reproduce exception:

In "Developer options" set "Background process limit" to "No background processes".
Open App below
Minimize App below and open 2 other apps
Open App below again
App below crashes with the exception

What is interesting is that App does not throw this exception if:

ComponentActivity is used instead of AppCompatActivity
Plain Strings is used for route instead of type safe Object

Is it Jetpack Compose bug?
App source code:
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            NavHost(
                navController = navController,
                startDestination = Login
            ) {
                composable<Login> {
                    LoginScreen()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun LoginScreen() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Login Screen",
            fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineLarge.fontSize
        )
    }
}

@Serializable
object Login

UPD:
Sample project: https://github.com/SlavaGrishanin/Compose-Bug-Sample
Video demonstration: https://youtube.com/shorts/u7pN7vgOSAE

You should file a bug against Navigation with a sample project that reproduces your issue.

I made a ticket: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/382679383
